# Pulling column inside row_array() by variable inside result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

So I am trying to verify a column and check if quantity is more than enough to continue. The problem I am having, is I'm trying to assign the column name using a variable, as such

```
 public function check_resc($data){
        
        $id = $this->session->userdata('char_id');
        
        $resc = trim($data['chng_resc']);
        $qty = trim($data['quantity']);
        $prov = trim($data['prov']);
        $ress = ucfirst($resc);
        
        $query = $this->db->select('*')
                          ->from('character_resources')
                          ->where('char_id', $id)
                          ->get();
        
        $result = $query->row_array();
        
        if($result[$ress] >= $qty){
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You do not have enough resources.'.$result[0].' / '.$qty);
            redirect(base_url('providence/view/'.$prov));
            return false;
        }

    }
```

In example, checking if they have enough "iron", I'm trying to access $result[$ress] >= $qty. But I can't assign the column im trying to pull through the result this way. How do I input the variable inside of $result[] to be able to pull that column? I've tried select($ress) and than using $result[0], no help. Also curly brackets {} are deprecated, so I need a alternative to make this work.

Comment: It's a little difficult to determine exactly what you're trying to do. Can you show an exmaple of what the `$query->row_array();` output is, and then what `$data` is in `check_resc($data)`?

Comment: the data is the three that are trimmed, chng_resc which is the resource, goes through ucfirst to get it down from Iron to iron. quantity is a int. prov is just used in the error. row_array, print out the array of the datatable : https://ibb.co/0q72PK3 
So the passing is Iron, 500, and Arizona, in example. And it should check the iron column and see if the quantity in there is more than or equal to the 500 passed. but error just shows : You do not have enough resources.  / 500 , so its not pulling the column at all

Comment: so in example, when i do say $result['iron'], it would show that column, and what im trying to do is pass that inside the variable that it's looking for. so doing $result[$ress] should be $result['iron'] if i pass Iron through it.

Comment: I would post this as an answer, but it's really a typo. You want `strtolower($resc)` - `ucwords()` is `UpperCaseWords` -- then `$result[$ress]` should work

Comment: wow i feel like an idiot.. thank you though!!

Comment: My guess is that you need to find out the dimension of $result array. Only then you can resolve it. Can you share output of $query->num_rows().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes. When you hard code the column name you wrap the text in quotes. For example **SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = "exampleId"**; When you substitute **exampleId** which is of **type String** you need to make sure that it is properly formatted. If the query is wrapped in *double quotes* try wrapping the variable in *single quotes* first unless you're using concatenation. Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

hello can you try using codeigniter queries as i wrote them bellow?

and if you use row_array it will return only the first row just to let you know

```
$this->db-where('char_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get('character_resources');
        
$result = $query->row_array();
// print_r($result);

if($result['the name of the column as it's showing after printing the results '] >= $qty){
  return true;
}
```

you can check this url to know more about sql queries in codeigniter framework
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

and as kinglish said :

You want `strtolower($resc)`- `ucwords()` is `UpperCaseWords` -- then `$result[$ress]` should work
i hope you found this answer helpful